# Deleting a specific hash inside an array of hashes using a variable

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have an array of hashes like this:

```
"[{:id=>15, :name=>"Hockey", :num_of_boxes=>2, :total_price=>6.98}, {:id=>14, :name=>"Baseball", :num_of_boxes=>3, :total_price=>8.97}, {:id=>5, :name=>"Basketball", :num_of_boxes=>2, :total_price=>5.98}]"
```

In my controller I want to delete the hash where the ID is set as a variable elsewhere. How would I go about doing this?

This is what I was trying to get to work, and I think it's the right path? id would be set in the controller before this method runs:

```
new_array = eval(@garden.seed_cart).reject { |h| id.include? h['15'] }
```

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Why is your "array of hashes" actually a string?

Comment: Just the way the previous programmer did the code. I'm just trying to add something on top of it.

Comment: I don't know why everyone's using `include?` - isn't it a straight comparison? Ie. `arr.delete_if { |h| id == h[:id] }` ?

Comment: I used `include?` because the original code snippet used it. For that reason I assumed that there might be multiple IDs that the poster would be filtering. But yes, if there is only one ID then a straightforward comparison with `==` would work. I've edited my answer to reflect this. Thanks, @smathy!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
arr.delete_if { |hash| id.include?(hash[:id]) }
```

Note (comparison to the `#reject` suggestion): `#delete_if` returns the unchanged array if there is nothing to delete. `#reject` returns `nil`. Also, `#delete_if` modifies the array in place, whereas `#reject` (without `!`) simply returns a changed version of the array but leaves the original unchanged.

**edit**
Note: the use of `include?` here assumes that there may be multiple integers that are being filtered out, i.e. if `id` (or `ids`) is actually an array. If you just need to filter one ID, you can use a straightforward comparison with `hash[:id] == id` inside the block. Thanks to smathy for pointing this out in the comments.

Comment: Thanks that worked great. I gave you the checkmark for specifying why #delete_if is a more robust solution.

Answer (score 0):

If you have this data:

```
data = [{:id=>15, :name=>"Hockey", :num_of_boxes=>2, :total_price=>6.98}, {:id=>14, :name=>"Baseball", :num_of_boxes=>3, :total_price=>8.97}, {:id=>5, :name=>"Basketball", :num_of_boxes=>2, :total_price=>5.98}]
```

And you want to remove this ids from data:

```
ids = [14,15]
```

You can do

```
new_array = data.reject { |h| ids.include? h[:id] }
```

And you get

```
new_array = [{:id=>5, :name=>"Basketball", :num_of_boxes=>2, :total_price=>5.98}]
```

Note: `data` in an array (not a string) and `ids` is an array too.

Comment: Thanks for the solution, it works well but I gave the correct answer to the poster above because it's a more robust way of doing it.